# Signing a single jar (for an applet) among hundreds in a web application. Application server does not come up

Tags: java, jar, applet, sign

I followed the steps to create a self certificate (using keytool) and then used jarsigner to sign the jar that contains my applets without any errors. I have many other jars in the WEB-INF/lib directory of my web application. But every time I do this, restart my application server and browse to the home page of my application I get a 500 error.

I was wondering if there is an additional step after jarsigner that I should perform. Maybe update the server.xml etc? I am using the Oracle Application Server 10g (I know!)

The main issue I am trying to solve is, for the last 2-3 weeks all users are getting a dialogue box when the webpage has applets. I am trying to sign the jar that contains my applets. I also tried to sign all the jars, but I had the same issue. The web application stopped responding.

Comment: Why is the applet jar in the webapp libraries in the first place? Not only the applet shouldn't be in the classpath of the webapp, but by putting it there, the browser won't be able to download it. An applet jar file is just like an image, HTML or CSS file. It should be stored with the rest of the downloadable resources of the webapp. Not under WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: We are using a COTS application and I think the jar contains other things besides the applet classes. In any case all jar files came packaged in the WEB-INF/lib folder. The application has been running fine like this for the last 3+ years without incident.

Comment: I don't see how that might be possible (unless you have a servlet reading the jar file in memory and streaming it to the response). But anyway, check your logs, and read the error messages that you should find in there.

Comment: Yes - you are right. There is a class loader servlet that loads all the jar files etc.